# Prevent viewing certain .php files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using PHP with Apache and pretty URLs with mod_rewrite.

I have an `index.php` where I include some other .php files that contain the content.
Now I'd like to prevent people from viewing those (content only) .php files, unless they are included via my `index.php` script of course.

This is the RewriteRule I'm using:
`RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9/-]+)/?$ /index.php [NC,L]`

It rewrites every request to the index.php where requests are handled and content is included accordingly.

Is there a way to do this with `mod_rewrite`, i.e. my `.htaccess`? To generally deny access to .php files or something like that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>How do you access these files currently if all requests are rewritten to index.php? You should not need to deny access.</strike>

Use

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

and handle everything else in PHP.

Comment: I just type them into the address bar and it seems to work. Doesn't matter if they are in the same folder as index.php or some subfolder. Again, that's the rule I'm using: `RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9/-]+)/?$ /index.php [NC,L]`

Comment: How about using `^(.*)$ /index.php [L]` and doing all of the work in your `index.php`? This gives you full control and is less verbose than using a check in every file.

Comment: I think I've tried this before and couldn't get it to work. I'm getting 500 server errors. Apache's error.log says: "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace." Any idea?

Comment: @user367217: Try `^(.*)$ index.php [L]`.

Answer (score 4):

Put a constant in you index file and then in each php file do something like:

```
defined('ALLOWED') or die('No direct script access.');
```

Comment: You can also put the php files above the public path.

Comment: Thanks, I actually used to do it that way but figured using mod_rewrite would be a better approach since I wouldn't have to manually check for a constant in every file.

Answer (score 4):

Keep your PHP files (except index.php) out of the web root.  You can still include/require them from your code, but people won't be able to access them by URL.